# Why do I get ".htaccess: Options not allowed here" when I try to run my Perl script in a browser?

Tags: apache, perl, .htaccess

I am getting "Internal Server Error" along with the following error when I execute my Perl script in my browser:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, xxxxx@att.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

When I enable the error log, I see the following error:

> [Wed Apr 15 15:36:08 2015] [alert] [client 135.75.222.51] /var/www/html/oncall/cgi-bin/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

Comment: Do you have access to the error logs? If so, please find the exact error message and [edit] it into your question. If not, you can add `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` to the top of your script to show fatal errors directly in the browser (assuming this is a vanilla CGI script and you're not using a framework). Also, please [edit] the relevant bits of your script into the question.

Comment: I enable the errorlog I am getting following error :       [Wed Apr 15 15:36:08 2015] [alert] [client 135.75.222.51] /var/www/html/oncall/cgi-bin/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

Comment: That means that your Apache configuration doesn't allow `Options` directives in .htaccess files. This is controlled by [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride), which is probably set in your main httpd.conf.

Comment: Anything I need to change in .htaccess file??.

Comment: What content I need to add in httpd.conf file, Please anyone tell me.

Comment: See the Apache documentation I linked in my previous comment. There's a section explicitly related to allowing `Options` in .htaccess.

Comment: I disagree with ThisSuitIsBlackNot. There's no indication that user3829086 has `AllowOverride All` set in his `httpd.conf`.

Comment: @ikegami Not `AllowOverride All`, no. That error indicates that the OP has something besides `AllowOverride All` (which would not cause an error), besides `AllowOverride None` (in which case, Apache wouldn't even attempt reading .htaccess files), and besides `AllowOverride Options`. For example, setting `AllowOverride FileInfo` and then putting an `Options` directive in .htaccess gives this error.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, The question you said was a dup didn't work even though it had `AllowOverride All`. Different question.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, I see what you're saying. I missed that part in the other question. Good catch (yet again).

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/oncall/cgi-bin/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: I have added above solution in .htaccess file along with actual path of cgi-bin . But It is not working..

Comment: I am getting following error in error log:     /var/www/html/oncall/cgi-bin/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here

Comment: The <Directory> block goes in your httpd.conf or whatever your install uses (maybe apache2.conf).  You can also put it in the <VirtualHost> block if you have one.  The details are in the Apache documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory